# Python plot 6*6 heatmap

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a 1258*12 matrix, where the first 6 columns I want to use as x axis of heatmap, and last 6 columns as y axis. 
The question is: this is not a 6*6 matrix but a 1258*12 matrix, how can I plot a 6*6 heatmap based on my data?
My code as follows:

```
column_labels = ['EMAcrossover1', 'EMAcrossover3', 'EMAcrossover7',
   'EMAcrossover10', 'EMAcrossover20', 'EMAcrossover40']
row_labels = ['return1', 'return3', 'return7', 'return10', 'return20', 'return30']
data = df[:] # df is my 1258*12 dataframe
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax.pcolor(data)
# put the major ticks at the middle of each cell
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1])+0.5, minor=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(row_labels, minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, minor=False)
plt.show()
```

df is like follow:

[df.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/curi5.png)

followed by 1258*12 lines of numbers

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Can you add your code to question, what do you try?

Comment: hi sorry, i just added my code sample

Comment: Super, but what your `df` ? Is possible share data? Or better is possible add sample of data?

Comment: Insufficient description. heat map means you have (x,y) position and another value (temperature). Please describe again what is x, y and what is temperature. I only see x,y from your description.

Comment: Hi Sung, pls take a look at the updated picture. The x should be row_labels, y should be column_labels, and temp should be the corresponding values in df.pic. However, the value here have two (which are e.g. EMAcrossover1' value and return3's value)

Comment: I think i found the answer. I need to firstly calculate the correlation between each two columns to get a 6*6 matrix for my data. Then apply the above code to get the heatmap.